# New to Linux; Downloaded for emulator OS

Tags: ppa, 19.04, ubuntu-emulator

Hello I am VERY new to Linux when I started I bought a thumb drive and decided to Install Ubuntu 19.04 to a partition on my Internal Drive.
I looked for some classic NES emulators and Playstation emulators.
As looking for some emulators I found out that there is an apt already in the files of Ubuntu so I opened to terminal and ran the command to install PCSXR.
Looking for some ROMS to download to play on my newly installed emulator the files were mostly .zip as a big time Windows fan I extracted them and looked for a Setup.exe application to run the install but can't seem to find them any files.
I also tried to downloading some other emulators and adding some PPA but I got an error message reading

```
alexdavis1998@Alex-Davis:~$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa
The Official pcsx2 ppa, provided by the pcsx2 team. This ppa contains a
regular package snapshot of pcsx2. We are not package experts, but we
try to follow the debian policy.

* We suggest you use https//github.com/PCSX2/pcsx2/issues to
report issues with pcsx2.

* The package is 32bit only,  but can be installed on systems that fully
support multiarch. You need at least Ubuntu Precise.

* This PPA provides the latest stable versions (1.4). Daily unstable build can be downloaded from this https://launchpad.net/~pcsx2-team/+archive/ubuntu/pcsx2-daily

* PPA doesn't allow to upload package on unsupported Ubuntu. In short it only remains LTS and latest version.
More info: https//launchpad.net/~gregory-hainaut/+archive/ubuntu/pcsx2.official.ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Ign:1 http//dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http//security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease
Hit:3 http//us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:4 http//us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http//dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Hit:6 http//us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease
Ign:7 http//ppa.launchpad.net/gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease
Ign:8 http//ppa.launchpad.net/sergio-br2/vbam-trunk/ubuntu disco InRelease
Err:10 http//ppa.launchpad.net/gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa/ubuntu disco Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:11 http//ppa.launchpad.net/sergio-br2/vbam-trunk/ubuntu disco Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http//ppa.launchpad.net/gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http//ppa.launchpad.net/sergio-br2/vbam-trunk/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Is this because Ubuntu 19.04 was just released and isn't supported by alot of PPA's yet.
I'm stuck and thinking of deleting the OS and going to an older version 18.04

Thanks for all the help

Comment: I'm sorry, but what was wrong with installing both packages from official repository by running `sudo apt install pcsxr` (for [pcsxr](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=PCSXR)) and `sudo apt install pcsx2` (for [`pcsx2`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=+pcsx2&searchon=names))?

Comment: Could you clarify what is your question? Thank you.

Comment: I guess the OP's real problem is that they don't know how to run the (hopefully legally obtained) ROMs. @Alex Davis PlayStation games are not installed. AFAIK PCSXR supports running games from physical CD-ROMs, ISO files and BIN/CUE files. You'll also need an original BIOS for many games to run properly. And keep in mind that PlayStation games, although they are old, are not free. Unless you already own a legitimate copy of the game, downloading it is illegal in most countries. And even if you have a legitimate copy, it may be illegal depending on where you live.

Answer (score 1):

Try retroarch.
add the ppa with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libretro/stable && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install retroarch*
```

for stable 
or

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libretro/testing && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install retroarch*
```

for testing. After that install the cores for the emulator you want.
(from https://www.retroarch.com/index.php?page=linux-instructions)

Answer (score 0):

As ppa's are unofficial, you have to depend on the maintainers, sometimes a single person. Some ppas will only provide packages for (the last) LTS, some only for the last version. As `19.04` is relatively new, it might take some days/weeks until the maintainers have packages ready.

---

There is a related issue on the github account ([Ubuntu Cosmic repository does not have a release file](https://github.com/PCSX2/pcsx2/issues/2802)).

With the author answering:

> I don't plan to add it for multiples reasons
>
> - I don't have any free time
> - Some GCC workarounds must be backported to 1.4 branch (back to first point)
> - 1.4 is rather outdated
>
> There is another ppa available with latest dev version (check
>   pcsx2.net for the link).

The issue is about `18.10`, but I assume it is the same for `19.04`.

---

You can use the [daily builds ppa](https://launchpad.net/~pcsx2-team/+archive/ubuntu/pcsx2-daily) instead:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pcsx2-team/pcsx2-daily
sudo apt install pcsx2.snapshot
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend to use official packages - [pcsxr](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=PCSXR) and [`pcsx2`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=+pcsx2&searchon=names).

So you remove the problematic PPAs with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:sergio-br2/vbam-trunk
```

and install packages from universe repository with

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt install pcsxr pcsx2
```